# Computing $F^*(\omega^2_1)$ for a Darboux Frame of a surface in $\mathbb{E}^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, surfaces

**Question:** I am trying to compute the pullback of the Maurer-Cartan form for a Darboux Frame of a surface in $\mathbb{E^3}$, and I seem to have gotten a bit stuck. Here is the question:

> Let $F: U^2 \rightarrow E(3)$ be the Darboux lift of a map $f:U^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{E}^3$ where $E(3)$ is the Euclidean group. Compute $F^*(\omega^2_1)$.

**My attempt:** I am going to use $\bar{\omega}$ to stand for $F^*(\omega)$ here to avoid cumbersome notation. Since we are using a Darboux frame, we know that 
$$\bar{\omega}^3_1 = \kappa_1 \bar{\omega}^1\\ \bar{\omega}^3_2 = \kappa_2\bar{\omega}^2.$$

Taking the derivatives of these functions and using the Cartan structure equations we can get that
$$(\kappa_2-\kappa_1)\bar{\omega}^2_1\wedge\bar{\omega}^1 = d\kappa_2\wedge\bar{\omega}^2\\ (\kappa_2-\kappa_1)\bar{\omega}^2_1\wedge\bar{\omega}^2 = d\kappa_1\wedge\bar{\omega}^1$$

We can then rearrange the above equations to get the following:
$$((\kappa_1-\kappa_2)\bar{\omega}^2_1 + d\kappa_1)\wedge \bar{\omega}^1 + ((\kappa_1-\kappa_2)\bar{\omega}^2_1 + d\kappa_2)\wedge \bar{\omega}^2 = 0$$

So, using Cartan's lemma, we know that there exist functions $h_{ij}$ such that
$$\begin{pmatrix}(\kappa_1-\kappa_2)\bar{\omega}^2_1 + d\kappa_1\\ (\kappa_1-\kappa_2)\bar{\omega}^2_1 + d\kappa_2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}h_{11} & h_{12}\\ h_{12} & h_{22}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\bar{\omega}^1\\ \bar{\omega}^2\end{pmatrix}.$$

However, solving this system to determine my functions $h_{ij}$ is giving me a bit of trouble. I feel like I should be able to explicitly determine these functions, but the method to do it is escaping me currently. Any help on this would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! You just need to decompose these into components. Let's note that 
$$\bar{\omega}^2_1 = \lambda_1\bar{\omega}^1 + \lambda_2\bar{\omega}^2$$
and similarly, decompose 
$$d\kappa_i = \kappa_{i,1}\bar{\omega}^1 + \kappa_{i,2}\bar{\omega}^2$$
Then we can reduce the equations
$$(\kappa_2-\kappa_1)\bar{\omega}^2_1\wedge\bar{\omega}^1 = d\kappa_2\wedge\bar{\omega}^2\\ (\kappa_2-\kappa_1)\bar{\omega}^2_1\wedge\bar{\omega}^2 = d\kappa_1\wedge\bar{\omega}^1$$
to
$$(\kappa_2-\kappa_1)\lambda_2\bar{\omega}^2\wedge\bar{\omega}^1 = \kappa_{2,1}\bar{\omega}^1\wedge\bar{\omega}^2\\ (\kappa_2-\kappa_1)\lambda_1\bar{\omega}^1\wedge\bar{\omega}^2 = \kappa_{1,2}\bar{\omega}^2\wedge\bar{\omega}^1.$$
These equations are easy to reduce to get that 
$$\bar{\omega}^2_1 = \frac{\kappa_{1,2}\bar{\omega}^1 + \kappa_{2,1}\bar{\omega}^2}{\kappa_1-\kappa_2}.$$